# sqlalchemy raw sql query limit using connection.execute()

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This python code should run statements on the database, but the sql statements are not executed:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
sql_file = open("test.sql","r")
sql_query = sql_file.read()
sql_file.close()
engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@localhost/test', echo=False)

conn = engine.connect()
print sql_query
result = conn.execute(sql_query)
conn.close()
```

The `test.sql` file contains SQL statements which create 89 tables.

The tables are not created if I specify 89 tables, but if I reduce the number of tables to 2 to it works.

Is there a limit on the number of queries that can be executed within the conn.execute?  How do a run any number of raw queries like this?

Comment: Seems like you are not committing your create table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps, forcing the autocommit:

```
conn.execute(RAW_SQL).execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

Other approach is using transactions and doing the commit:

```
t = conn.begin()
try:
    conn.execute(RAW_SQL)
    t.commit()
except:
    t.rollback()
```

PD: You can put the execution_options in the create_engine parameters too.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use raw SQL with SQLAlchemy? If you have no good reason for that, you should use other methods:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#metadata-describing

Comment: you are right, i was using psycopg2 before hand and this was my first dabble with sqlalchemy

Comment: I don't believe you can ignore the case for tuning an app with SQL. An ORM often gets it right, but sometimes you need to be able to handle cases like these.

Comment: @MatthewB.Gray In my experience, it only gets it right when you're doing very simple operations. Or it makes fashioning the query a living hell.